# Android VideoView load Audio/Video file from assets

Tags: java, android, eclipse, video

I want to play a video located in the assests folder of my application

I get a message 'Impossible to play the video'

I guess the path is incorrect

this the code :

```
String fileName = "android.resource://"+  getPackageName() +"/assets/video.3gp";
VideoView vv = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.surface);
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
vv.start();
```

Comment: Internal Storage? do you mean into the assets folder?

Comment: yes I mean assets folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to play that file from `\assets`, you must load from `\raw` folder.

In your project create a folder `\raw` inside `\res` and paste your video file.

```
String fileName = "android.resource://"+  getPackageName() + "/raw/video";
VideoView vv = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.surface);
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
vv.start();
```

Comment: R.raw.video.3gp; ? there is an error, some " missing ?

Comment: sorry without extension!

Comment: I still get E/MediaPlayer(32297): Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: I set your answer has correct because it respond to the question, but now I got another problem, I still can't get the video I got the Error (1,-2147483648), Thanks you anyway :)

Comment: thank you, now if you look for info about that error probably you can´t find an answer, but for my experience is related to the Codecs, this method works for my files, Audio codec AAC, Video Codec H.264.

Comment: which software are you using to set this codec to the video ?

Comment: Sorenson spark https://www.sorensonmedia.com/video-codec and Apple compressor https://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/compressor/

Comment: I didn't saw your last edit, the problem is now solved